# Adding span with a checkbox inside bootstrap select

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

What I want to achieve (or rather, hope to achieve) is best described in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sf4rth06/)

I want to place an input inside the [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/) element. I don't even sure that it's possible. Any suggestions ?

```css
/* ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
table {
    table-layout: fixed;
}

th.zeon-fixed-narrow-column {
 width: 4.5em;
  display:inline-block; 
}

.zeon-selectpicker{
   border:none !important;
   width: 1.5em;
}

.bootstrap-select:not([class*="span"]):not([class*="col-"]):not([class*="form-control"]):not(.input-group-btn){
  width:100%;
}

.zeon-fixed-narrow-column .bootstrap-select button{
  background-color:transparent;
}
```

```html
<table id='order_drafts_table' class="form table zeon zeon-row-hover ">
  <thead class='zeon-small-headings'>
    <th class='zeon-fixed-narrow-column'>  
      <select class="selectpicker show-tick zeon-selectpicker" multiple title="">
        <option title="">Все</option>
        <option title="">С ненулевым выбранным заказом</option>
        <option title="">С ненулевым рекоммендованным заказом</option>
      </select>
    </th>
    <th>
     ABC
    </th>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the point of the span? Could you not do what you want with an option that is disabled?

Comment: It's just a matter of design. It's not necessarily an input. A simple span with some Bootstrap component will do

Comment: Use plugin: [multiple select](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/multiple-select/docs/#multiple-select)

Comment: dm4web, that's not an answer to my question, and yet - THANK YOU FOR THIS !!!